# JavaScript: присвоить ключ объекту равный значению переменной

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в Javascript присвоить ключ объекту равный значению переменной? Например:

```
person = {};
val = 'Имя';
name = 'Вася'

person.val = name;
```

Результатом будет объект: `person = {val: "Вася"}`

Но мне нужно записать само **значение** переменной `val`, которое равно строковому значению `'Имя'`, чтобы в итоге получить такой объект:

```
`person = {"Имя": "Вася"}`
```

Подскажите, как это сделать?

Спасибо!

Comment: @Grundy, о, спасибо, король рускоязычного JS! Вот так решилось : `person[val] = name;`

Comment: Он у нас монарх.